Proving all natural number solutions of $\sqrt{6n+1} = b$, are all the natural numbers that do not contain 2 or 3 as a factor.
I'm an amateur math man, and I just like playing around with numbers in Excel and seeing what I find. Recently I've become interested in natural number solutions to the expression.
$\sqrt{nm + c} = b$
Where $a,b,n,m \in N$
I've noticed that all values of $b$ in...
$\sqrt{6n+1} = b$
That are natural numbers, have the same thing in common; they all don't contain 2 or 3 as a factor; thus, all the primes are there. I want to prove this result, but unfortunately, I have no idea how to go about it. I am interested in learning how to prove results, so if anyone has a hot tip for how I might approach this, it would be much appreciated.

Hint: $,2\cdot 3\mid b^2!-!1=(b!-!1)(b!+!1)!\iff! 2\mid b!-!1,$ & $,3\mid b\pm1!\iff! 2\nmid b,$ & $,3\nmid b\ \ $

Generally see the linked dupe for how to solve such modular quadratics. $\ \ $

Let $b$ be some natural number such that for some $n\in \mathbb N$, $\sqrt{6n+1}$ is an integer.
That $b$ is odd is easier to show. Assume not; then $b=2k$ for some $k\in \mathbb N$, which means that
$$6n + 1 = 4k^2 \Rightarrow (3n-2k^2) = \dfrac{1}{2},$$ which cannot be true for natural numbers $n$ and $k$ because the .
Similarly, assume that $3|b$. Then be is similarly of the form $3k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$. Which, again, gives us that
$$6n+1 = 9k^2 \Rightarrow (2n-3k^2) = \dfrac{1}{3},$$ a similar contradiction. This proves that every natural number of the form $\sqrt{6n+1}$ cannot have $2$ or $3$ as factors.
This does not, however, prove that every prime is there. We have showed that no number that is divisible by $2$ or $3$ can have this form; which was your original question. It is a necessary condition, not a sufficient one. A number may be indivisible by $2$ and $3$ while being divisible by other primes (say $5$), we have said nothing about numbers of that form. Your initial claim, and my proof, says nothing about say $b = 35$. To prove the much stronger second claim, we must show the following:

Every integer not divisible by $2$ or $3$ can be expressed as $\sqrt{6n+1}$.

Why is this true? Any integer can be written as one of the following:
$$6k - 3, 6k -2, 6k -1, 6k, 6k +1, 6k -2.$$
Of these, $3$ divides $6k-3$ and $6k$. $2$ divides $6k -2, 6k, 6k+2$. Which leaves us with only $6k\pm1$ being the only forms that are divisible by neither $2$ or $3$.
If you take the squares, you'll get $36k^2\pm 12k+1= 6(6k^2\pm2k)+1$, implying that they take the form $6n+1$. This proves that every integer not divisible by $2$ or $3$, and thus all primes, can be expressed in that form.
Note: Typically, questions asking for solutions to such expressions look for solutions in $n$, not $b$.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to PSQs & dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
